# I'm only seeing keys instead of translations in iOS app

Tags: ios, localization, polyglot

I have an issue where only keys are shown in the app after new keys were pulled from polyglot. How to solve it?

Answer (score -1):

1. Check if your files are included in project
2. Check if your locale and translation filename match
3. Validate your file using `plutil -lint path/to/translation.strings`
4. Apparently there's an issue if there's only `";` in newline, check for those.